# How to set default_lon, default_lat for admin page using GISModelAdmin

Tags: python, django, gis, geodjango

How do you set default_lon, default_lat, and default_zoom for a PointField in the django admin page using GISModelAdmin class?

With the following code the admin page loads correctly, but with the default location in Europe.

model.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
class Enclosure(models.Model):
    location = models.PointField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

admin.py

```
from .models import Enclosure
@admin.register(Enclosure)
class EnclocusreAdmin(GISModelAdmin):
    pass
```

I've tried the following code to try to set default lat, lon for the widget. However doing this results in no map displayed for the PointField on the admin page.

admin.py

```
from .models import Enclosure
@admin.register(Enclosuer)
class EnclosureAdmin(GISModelAdmin):
    gis_widget_kwargs = {
        'attrs': {
            'default_lon': 40.383546,
            'default_lat': -111.774973,
        }
    }
```

The relevant Django code is

```
class GISModelAdmin(GeoModelAdminMixin, ModelAdmin):
    pass

class GeoModelAdminMixin:
    gis_widget = OSMWidget
    gis_widget_kwargs = {}

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if (
            isinstance(db_field, models.GeometryField) and
            (db_field.dim < 3 or self.gis_widget.supports_3d)
        ):
            kwargs['widget'] = self.gis_widget(**self.gis_widget_kwargs)
            return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
        else:
            return super().formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, request, **kwargs)

class OSMWidget(OpenLayersWidget):
    """
    An OpenLayers/OpenStreetMap-based widget.
    """
    template_name = 'gis/openlayers-osm.html'
    default_lon = 5
    default_lat = 47
    default_zoom = 12

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        super().__init__()
        for key in ('default_lon', 'default_lat', 'default_zoom'):
            self.attrs[key] = getattr(self, key)
        if attrs:
            self.attrs.update(attrs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Subclassing `GISModelAdmin` seems to work: In `admin.py`

```py
from django.contrib.gis import admin
from .models import Enclosure

class CustomGeoWidgetAdmin(admin.GISModelAdmin):
    gis_widget_kwargs = {
        'attrs': {
            'default_zoom': 11,
            'default_lon': 10,
            'default_lat': 43,
        },
    }

@admin.register(Enclosure)
class EnclosureAdmin(CustomGeoWidgetAdmin):
    pass
```

Comment: That's effectively what I was doing. The issue was that I was transposing lat and lon, and the location was not a valid coordinate. It does not throw an error, or change the location to the edge of the map like other systems I've used. The map simply doesn't load. I edited my question to show the actual coordinates I was using.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that there is nothing to verify that the latitude and longitude lie in the right range...

Comment: Setting `gis_widget_kwargs` for `admin.GISModelAdmin` does nothing. Am I doing something wrong here?